# What is the best way to work with large data sets in the Google App Engine Java Development server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a Java application using Google App Engine that depends on a largish dataset to be present. Without getting into specifics of my application, I'll just state that working with a small subset of the data is simply not practical. Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the Google App Engine for Java development server stores the entire datastore in memory. According to [Ikai Lan](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/e8c5d4947bc61593?pli=1):

> The development server datastore stub is an in memory Map that is persisted 
>   to disk.

I simply cannot import my entire dataset into the development datastore without running into memory problems. Once the application is pushed into Google's cloud and uses BigTable, there is no issue. But deployment to the cloud takes a long time making development cycles kind of painful. So developing this way is not practical.

I've noticed the Google App Engine for Python development server has an [option to use SQLite](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore) as the backend datastore which I presume would solve my problem.

> dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite

But the [Java development server includes no such option](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Command_Line_Arguments) (at least not documented). What is the best way to get a large dataset working with the Google App Engine Java development server?

Comment: You can try for hadoop, it will help you to handle large datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic solution - the only datastore stub for the Java API, currently, is an in-memory one. Short of implementing your own disk-based stub, your only options are to find a way to work with a subset of data for testing, or do your development on appspot.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, working with a subset of data is not always practical. Imagine for example a spell-check feature based on an incomplete dictionary. And developing on appspot means constantly deploying which is a slow multi-step process. That makes it kind of painful. Suppose I did want to implement my own disk based (maybe database driven) stub. How would I go about doing that? What hooks are available for me to plug in my implementation? If I get it working I would open source it on github.

Comment: @Asaph You could easily test a spell-check on a small dictionary - just select test cases that suit the data. If you can't pare your dataset down, you're going to have extreme trouble testing it. Building your own would require understanding the innards of the dev-appserver (source not released yet, but on its way), specifically the api_stub_map.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Ok, perhaps spell-check is not a perfect example. It's not my actual use case; just something I contrived to try to illustrate my point. And I only pondered building my own disk-based stub because I thought you were suggesting it might be possible in your answer. Are there any plans to offer more datastore stub options in the Java dev server similar to what's available in the Python dev server?

Comment: @Asaph It's certainly possible for you to do it, but it would be a significant undertaking. I'm just suggesting that a better alternative is probably to find a way to work with a subset of data, since having work with a large dataset impacts testability as well.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Please don't misunderstand me. I'm not using large data-sets in unit tests. I'm using `LocalServiceTestHelper` with `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig` as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html#Writing_Datastore_and_Memcache_Tests). My unit tests basically start with a blank datastore and insert a few rows of data in the `setUp` method before testing. So they run fast and use little memory. I'm already working with a subset of the data. But as my UI design emerges, it's becoming difficult for me to make informed UI decisions.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: +1. Thanks for your super helpful comments. I'm going to leave the question open for a while in case some enterprising programmer decides to tackle the disk-based implementation for the Java dev server. If Google decides to provide a solution, please update your answer. BTW: Great job on App Engine overall. We love it. Keep up the great work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the mapper api to import data from the blobstore, as described by Ikai Lan in this blog entry - http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/11/using-the-app-engine-mapper-for-bulk-data-import/.

I've found it to be much faster and more stable than using the remote api bulkloader - especially when loading medium sized datasets (100k entities) into the local datastore.